# How to set server in a server farm unhealthy in IIS7 automatically when requests are not served?

Tags: iis, arr

I am using ARR and URL Rewrite to route incoming requests to server farm. I have added two servers to server farm. If one of the servers is either not in network or shut down, the IIS console still shows the server as available and healthy. How to make the server unhealthy without manually changing its status.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a Health Test configured in IIS?

Comment: Yes. I did it but this will test URL after some specified interval again and again. Is there any other optimized way?